# Why does the subscription to Web Push notifications in Firefox disappear after a while? (Web Push API)

Tags: web, firefox, push-notification, frontend, mozilla

I really need help. I can't understand why Firefox kills properly registered push-subscription!?
In my app, I properly register a service Worker, get permission, and subscribe to push notifications. Then I save the subscription in my database and send PUSH notifications. Everything works well, in different browsers (Opera, Chrome, Firefox). But after a while when I send another push notification to Firefox I get a response:

`"code": 410, "errno": 106, "error": "", "more_info": "http://autopush.readthedocs.io/en/latest/http.html#error-codes", "message": "Request did not validate No such subscription"`

If re-subscribe, it starts working again for a while... This problem is ONLY with Mozilla Firefox, subscriptions for other browsers work ok!
I can't understand why the subscription disappears in Firefox? I use same script for all browsers, what is wrong with it in the case of mozilla, I can't understand. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I also saw this.  The service worker in `about:debugging` (detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers)) was stopped.